# Vb.net Excel Zoom to Selection

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm new to vb.net and coding for Excel applications. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I'm sure there is an easy solution to my question, but i cannot seem to find anything within any forums. I'm trying to select a range of cells and zoom to the selection. Selecting the cell range was accomplished by:

```
Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1", "T1").Select()
```

then zooming, I can only find a zoom member under the PageSetup property.

```
Globals.Sheet1.PageSetup.Zoom =
```

But it is looking for a Percentage, not a Range. In other forums I saw mention of `ActiveWindow.zoom = True` and then select the cell range and it should zoom, but the `ActiveWindow` does not work for me. Its not recognized .

Other potential option, but I do not know how to accomplish, is to provoke the *Zoom To Selection* button in the *View* toolbar.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference the object Application for active window in vb.net like so

```
objApp = New Excel.Application 'excel application

objApp.Workbooks.Worksheets(1).Select()
objApp.Workbooks.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", "T1").Select()

objApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom = True   'excel application
```

Comment: Steven thank you for your response. When using your example, it is saying that "Worksheets" is not a member of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks